# Kionix Accelerometers not recognizing Hinge Angle

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, accelerometer

I have a notebook that has two accelerometers in it, a third device called "HingeAngle Device" and a service called "HingeAngle Service" which is somehow coupled with that device. It uses all that to determine the angle (screen to keyboard) of my notebook, since it can rotate 360 degrees.

Yesterday I thought of updating all my drivers, which turned out to be a horrible idea. Both accelerometers updated to the latest version Windows could find, but now  it don't calculate anything anymore. I can fold the notebook to a tablet, it rotates, but the keyboard stays active.

[image: Now there are two software devices]

*(Now there are two **software components**, there was only one before)*

I already tried to download from the manufacturer's site of the notebook, but their driver doesn't even work. The HingeAngle Device doesn't appear there and the keyboard and touchpad stop working when I start the corresponding service.

When I look into the Windows's Event Log, I see that something failed to initialize:

[image: The device has an error]

And in the Device's property of the accelerometers it says "The device ACPI\KIOX010A\1 needs additional configuration".

I've spent the whole night on this and couldn't get it to work, neither revert it back. Google wasn't helpful also.

What do I need to do that it takes both sensors and calculates the Hinge Angle again?

Any clue is very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Download the file from this forum threead and run the setup.bat which will install the service that monitors the hinge.  Reboot after:

https://community.medion.com/t5/Notebook-Netbook/Medion-Akoya-E3216-nach-Clean-Install-geht-autom/td-p/53589

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Superuser! When providing answers, it is usually a good idea to provide the answer within the answer itself, instead of linking to external sites. Some of the reasons behind this is that external links can stop functioning (which would make the answer useless) and that is a nicer user experience to not having to leave the site when comparing several answers to the same question.

Comment: The instructions provided in the link didn't work - at least for me. The problem is as described by OP - keyboard and touchpad do not work anymore after installing the HingeAngle.